# Is my Find function following best practises

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to make sure my query to find models by ID is correct as I will be using this same pattern for all my structs/models.

```
func (dbs *DbService) GetUserLocationId(locationId int) (User, error) {
    var model User
    if dbs.deps.db.Where("location_id = ?", locationId).Find(&model).RecordNotFound() {
        return model, errors.New("User not found")
    }
    return model, nil
}
```

So a common usecase in a web application is to lookup a model, if it does not exist that I will insert a new record.

using the above I will do:

```
user, err := GetUserLocationById(123)
if err != nil {
  err := InsertNewUser(user)
}
```

Now what thing I am struggling with is this.  If the errors is not nil, then I should insert a new user.  But what if the error is because my query inside the function GetUserLocationById has the wrong column name?
I dont' want to start inserting rows when they really do exist.

Looking for some advice to make sure I am doing this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "best practices", it's better to post under [the dedicated SO website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

```
var ErrUserNotFound = errors.New("User not found")

func (dbs *DbService) GetUserLocationId(locationId int) (user User, err error)
    record := dbs.deps.db.Where("location_id = ?", locationId).Find(&user)
    if record.RecordNotFound() {
        err = ErrUserNotFound
    }
    return
}
```

Okay this is closer to the GO "best practices" standards IMHO. It's considered good practices to create package error values for commonly returned errors. It helps the caller handle each case properly (should there be), but it's not really the case here.

For the other snippet, you really won't want to do this like that. First of all you omitted the pointer receiver for both methods `GetUserLocationById` and `InsertNewUser`. Then, you usually don't want to shadow the parent's scope `err` variable, but it's *ok* here...

```
user, err := dbs.GetUserLocationById(123)
if err != nil {
   err = dbs.InsertNewUser(user)
   // handle err here
}
```

Anyways, I think that doing this with errors is too bad for there are no really other possibilities than "ErrUserNotFound" here. I would advise going for a `ok` boolean instead.

```
func (dbs *DbService) GetUserLocationId(locationId int) (user User, ok bool)
    record := dbs.deps.db.Where("location_id = ?", locationId).Find(&user)
    ok = !record.RecordNotFound()
    return
}
```

and then

```
var user User
if user, ok := dbs.GetUserLocationId(123); !ok {
    if err := dbs.InsertNewUser(user); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the where clause say you had this type: ```Where("locattttiiiooon_id = ?"``` Now with the above code that error will never be emitted and basically always insert new rows. - It should crash the request in my opinion, not sure how to do that either in the 'go way'

Comment: No I mean if a developer mistyped something, if we don't throw the error how will we know?  Allot of data will be corrupted by the time you find out there is an error that you didn't handle.  execution shouldn't' continue.

Comment: Execution **should** continue, but not this particular task, I admit it. But that's why you **must** write unit tests, make code reviews etc. Don't overload your code for programming mistakes that shouldn't happen anyways

Comment: Hmm I see, yeah it would simplify the usage that's for sure.  I just find in other languages it would just crash so always checking for err != nil has gotten me a bit muddled.